# Can we include User ID and Password with the intent to launch second application from first application?

Tags: android

I know you can launch a second app using something like:

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage
```

but I was wondering is there anyway to include a user/password so that the app launches with that information already in it or are we stuck having them log into the second app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add extras to this intent - these extras could contain a string ( token ) that authenticates the second app.